# what will be the java code to Fetch the data from database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

What will be the java code to fetch the last date for Reminder1 in the image given. [image]

This is what i have written but its wrong

```
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer("SELECT * FROM TITAN_PORTAL.Scorecard_Reminder whereStatus='Active'");
        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql.toString());
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String reminder1 = resultSet.getString("Reminder1.Last_Date");
```

Comment: It should be : ''' StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer("SELECT * FROM Scorecard_Reminder where Status='Active'");
        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql.toString());
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String reminder1 = resultSet.getString("Last_Date"); '''

Comment: There is nothing called `Reminder1` in your query.

Answer (score 3):

Use table `alias`. for easier retrieving of column names.

```
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer("SELECT * FROM TITAN_PORTAL.Scorecard_Reminder t1 whereStatus='Active'");
resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql.toString());
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String reminder1 = resultSet.getString("t1.Last_Date");
```

Comment: Be aware, this is a MySQL specific extension that will not work on other JDBC drivers. The JDBC standard way would be to use `resultSet.getString("Last_Date")`